# Convert iOS generated public Key for use in PHP openssl functions

Tags: php, ios, encryption, openssl

I want to verify an iOS client vie it's public key inside a PHP backend. At the moment, I am using the openssl library of PHP to verify/decrypt/encrypt data sent from the iOS device with a public key I got from it.

The problem is that the format of the iOS generated public key seems to be different from the one used by PHP's openssl functions.

Sample PHP generated public key (working nicely):

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAq7+3FfQ1CwjEMFeCRNKD
mRWwP1ddrqbVy5MeBLFp4lymWh4mPZ9E8LcMzQGLktcaht9T/k3pCJKJrMWGZIQY
MvAylKh3T80sadkPe8hCXOemiQvOs2vUu7pvk16kgcALjdyFlEUPnecngorX7DIX
AnMBgZkGuffDXC50UQ7ZPiCZUvUtDrOViVaKLB+a6DH6UMAJtLcvwRFHZ7oPJlna
NOMeZyphKYE1V8ik3sUix99t99C8iol6y+2pDnIrnS/TKVfKw3/VPEZqFFZ/q9vc
yjPPBy2gVV34eEbs6/hBWGDar1Iygl7X4VDUcl+0p+FK5vNTCqSPDN+twW1Qn65E
YQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Sample iOS generated public key:

```
7M9JAYATAQEAWAUAEMizCSAAAADJMywBs2cj4gb1J+qC+hIaqWhNtdEiSgB/3qwt
NP1uSx9aVQfGx9aghfYw69uOCkuE084eGifOI1NRAKJaovQdwhtAm9rLVmmg3euU
t86h30nNVeRhL4iG5y2J8gthYmJ2xREhRBo5uux+sUs=
```

Used functions in PHP:

```
openssl_public_decrypt();
```

So, is ther a nice way to convert the iOS formatted key to the one used by PHP?
What key format is iOS using anyways?

Comment: Seems I can convert PHP's keys to any desired format with http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/index.html, but not viceversa.